# Angular 4 and Ionic 3 No provider for HTTP

Tags: angular, ionic3

I have a service which imports Http, and when I use it in my app it throws error. "***No provider for Http! Error at g injectionError***". I am lazyloading the app. Also the provider was generated through cli "`ionic g provider ...`"

**complaint-service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class ComplaintService {
    private complaints: {subject: string, description: string}[] = [];

    constructor(public http: Http) {
        this.http = http;
        this.complaints = null;
        console.log('Hello ComplaintService Provider');
    }

    addComplaints(complaint: {subject: string, description: string}) {
        this.complaints.push(complaint);
    }

    getComplaints() {
        return this.complaints.slice();
    }

}
```

**complaint-form.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import {ComplaintService} from '../../providers/complaint-service';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-complaint-form',
  templateUrl: 'complaint-form.html',
  providers: [ComplaintService]
})
export class ComplaintForm {

}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You have to register the `Http` to the `providers` in your module

Comment: @devqon - do we need it while lazy loading also?

Comment: Note the difference between **`Http`** from Angular to **`HTTP`** from Ionic's native plugins. In case of getting a `no provider error` for the latter, include `HTTP` - _which can be imported from `ionic-native`_ - into your `app.module.ts`.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You have to register the `HttpModule` to your  module (`/app.module.ts`):

```
import { HttpModule} from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    HttpModule
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: In the ts file where your app module class is defined

Comment: i add this code in my project in: `testIonic/src/app/app.module.ts` and it works :)

Comment: In an app built with angular-cli place this code in the app.module.ts in the top folder.

Answer (score 4):

Add `HTTP` to the providers list as well. (to `AppModule`)

```
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http';
```

And

```
  providers: [
    ...,
    HTTP 
  ]
```

Working with Angulat5+, Ionic 3+

Answer (score 0):

HttpModule is deprecated in the latest version of ionic3 and Angular5. So, you have to use HttpClientModule instead of HttpModule. Other things will be same as @devqon's answer. After that, you can use HttpClient in your service or component file.

For more info, please refer to the original document of Angular.

https://angular.io/guide/http

```
import {HttpClientModule} from "@angular/common/http";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule
 ],
 declarations: [ AppComponent ],
 bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import {HttpClientModule} from "@angular/common/http";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ChatPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(ChatPage),
    HttpModule,
    HttpClientModule,// add HttpClientModule to import
    SocketIoModule.forRoot(config)
  ],

})
```

Dont forget to run with **ionic cordova run browser** because you need a platform to run cordova plugins